# How to get values of the keys with help data variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt.js project and I can't get values of the keys(containertransport) with help data variable(url).
If I put the word containertransport like that  {{item.containertransport}} it will be work.

```js
<template>
  <div>

    <p class="p_1" v-for="(item, index) in description_p1_text">
      {{ item.url }}
    </p>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {

    data: function () {
      return {

        url: 'containertransport',

        description_p1_text: [
          {
            containertransport: 'containertransport Das Unternehmen SEO GmbH erbringt Dienstleistungen im Bereich des Suchmaschinen-Marketings und' +
            'der Internetseitenoptimierung.'
          },

          {
            containertransport: 'containertransport Die Vertragsparteien sind sich der Besonderheiten des Verlinkungswesens bewusst und vereinbaren ' +
            'im Sinne der gegenseitigen Rücksichtnahme die nachfolgenden Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen.'
          },

          {
            containertransport: 'containertransport Die nachfolgenden allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen. Das Unternehmen SEO GmbH erbringt' +
            'Dienstleistungen im Bereich des Suchmaschinen-Marketings und der Internetseitenoptimierung. Die ' +
            'Vertragsparteien sind sich der Besonderheiten des Verlinkungswesens bewusst und vereinbaren im Sinne ' +
            'der gegenseitigen Rücksichtnahme die nachfolgenden Allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingungen.'
          },

        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

My question is: 
How can I do this with the data variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
<p class="p_1" v-for="(item, index) in description_p1_text">
  {{ item[url] }}
</p>
```